# why the rust rocket health shows 404 not found

Tags: rust

I am implement the health check api in rust rocket like this:

```
rocket_healthz::healthz!();

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build()
        .mount("/actuator/health", routes![healthz])
}
```

but when I access the health api using this command:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:11014/actuator/health
```

shows result like this:

```
root@dolphin-music-service-6768d8497f-fwvjj:/app# curl http://127.0.0.1:11014/actuator/health
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <div role="main" align="center">
        <h1>404: Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested resource could not be found.</p>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div role="contentinfo" align="center">
        <small>Rocket</small>
    </div>
</body>
```

where am I doing wrong? what should I do to fix this problem? By the way, this is the rocket health cargo dependencies:

```
rocket_healthz = "0.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/rocket_healthz/0.2.0/rocket_healthz/), it looks like it adds the `/healthz` part itself. So as written, calling the endpoint `/actuator/health/healthz` should work.

I do not see a way for you to customize the route if you wanted `/health` instead of `/healthz`.

Answer (score 2):

The used macro from `rocket_health` set up a route under `/healthz` so the final endpoint is `http://127.0.0.1:11014/actuator/health/healthz`.

If you neglect the generated test code, the remaining code for the health endpoint is trivial such that you can probably avoid the crate at all, see https://docs.rs/rocket_healthz/0.2.0/src/rocket_healthz/lib.rs.html#43-46